# OPEN FEINT error in Android App

Tags: android, andengine, openfeint

```
15 reports
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.oas.fruitkungfufree/com.openfeint.internal.ui.IntroFlow}: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.openfeint.internal.Util.setOrientation(Util.java:36)
at com.openfeint.internal.ui.NestedWindow.onCreate(NestedWindow.java:32)
at com.openfeint.internal.ui.WebNav.onCreate(WebNav.java:93)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
```

Does any one have a solution for this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a problem with your code, you can't use an object that is null. **This is a hint**.

Comment: you do realize that when the orientation changes.. onCreate() gets called again.. often times accessing SPECIFIC views after this is not a good idea. UNTIL after they are assigned.

Comment: but why should the orientation change if I have hardcoded it to landscape in manifest?

Comment: Check if it does go into the method that gives you a callback when the orientation changed. And this will answer your question.